# How many arms should a 5.8m long awning have?

Tags: exterior

I am preparing to install two awnings with folding aluminum arms.
The length of each awning is 5.80 meters or 19 ft. 
The house is at an elevation of 200 meters or 656ft (in the city outskirts) and has winds at about 5-6 Beauforts (30mph) maximum.

I have contacted four contractors to ask for prices.

Two of them suggested that two arms for each awning should be sufficient (after 6 meter or 20 ft they add a third one) and a third arm is not needed but it may cause problems.

The other two suggested that we should put three arms in order to have a solid construction.

I am trying to decide but I am not sure who is correct.

Please share any ideas or knowledge that you may have.

Comment: There are a lot of variables here that are going to be hard to account for over the internet. Could you post a picture with a rough sketch overlayed? Will snow loading be an issue? What are the awning frames made of? Etc. It's very likely that both contractors are "right" if it's right on the verge of needing 3.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will post a picture and details ASAP. The frames are aluminum ( in Greece there are basically two types , heavy and normal - with respect to the quantity of the metal and width of the profile). I will ask the contractor about the type of the profile he intends to use. Just for a comparison the price for an awning in Greece is approximately 140 USD per meter (length).

Comment: ...and snow is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

More is always better, I'd easily go with the guys putting a post every 10'. 2 poles would be okay if the bridge pole is a much larger diameter, which may be unsightly. That's still a pretty good wind to keep that sail down & everything better be bolted & not just screwed.